# Firebase Cloud Messaging Using Ruby Showing Invalid Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After letting the server run for a few hours cloud messaging begins to return the following (truncated response below).

`{:body=>"{\"error\":\"InvalidToken\"}", :response=>"Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields."}`

Once I restart Apache and attempt to resend the Firebase Cloud Message it will successfully send.

`{:body=>"{\"message_id\":4439418067666362930}", :status_code=>200, :response=>"success"}`

I know the token is valid as it will send correctly once apache has been restarted. I am using Ruby Rails with FCM gem 0.0.6

fcm (0.0.6)

Comment: Were you able to figure out the cause? I'm having the exact same issue and can't quite figure out what's happening after letting the server run for a few hours